# Call completion handler on background fetch with multiple NSURLSessions

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have multiple web services to be checked and downloaded in the background of my app, using `NSURLSession` to do this. When the app is in the background I use this code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    [self methodToStartAllDownloads];
    //Completion handler called somehow
}
```

The problem is that since all NSURLSessions have a completion handler and working async, it's hard to know when all of them are finished, so that I can call `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData)` in the method above. Is there a way to achieve something like calling the completion handler when all downloads are complete?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I used a global variable to count the number of completed downloads and call the completion handler when all downloads were done. However, this is not a very good solution and I'm still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the completion handler after `[self methodToStartAllDownloads];`, when you use NSURLSession with a background configuration, your downloads and uploads are handed to the system who will wake your app up once all of your tasks are completed.

I suggest you read this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44) to understand the NSURLSession background better